# MariaDB unexpected token near returning

Tags: mariadb

so I set up a new MariaDB Database and tried to insert some data into a table with this code:

```
INSERT INTO address VALUES (default, 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test') RETURNING id;
```

This is my table structure:

[image]

The error I am getting is telling me that there is an unexpected token near "Returning id" and I really don't have any idea, what exactly is wrong here.

I am using: 10.4.22-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution.
Can anyone help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'The RETURNING clause was introduced in MariaDB 10.5.' - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/

Comment: I have made a complete clean install to10.6.5-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution and I still get the same error.

Comment: Removed the [tag:mysql] tag because this question is asking about a feature specific to MariaDB.

Comment: Works fine here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4b5646316e7c4c917ab27af149fde477 please double check your version (as shown)